# Getting Error 500 in oozie on localhost

Tags: java, tomcat, hadoop, bigdata, oozie

On browsing oozie on http://localhost:11000/oozie/

It shows following error on the webpage-

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 25 in the generated java file
The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:451)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:321)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:328)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    org.apache.oozie.servlet.AuthFilter$2.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:126)
    org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:585)
    org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:548)
    org.apache.oozie.servlet.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:131)
    org.apache.oozie.servlet.HostnameFilter.doFilter(HostnameFilter.java:84)
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I removed the below files from oozie installation directory.

/oozie/oozie-server/webapps/oozie/WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar

/oozie/oozie-server/webapps/oozie/WEB-INF/lib/jsp-api-2.0.jar

And the oozie web console started working

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It would be great if you could add some explanation.

Comment: The above two jars and the classes in it is also available in the below directory
/oozie/libext/
This causes the error

Comment: Seeing the same problem.  However there is no jar in my `/usr/lib/oozie/libext`.  Any help ?

Comment: WOW! Saved the day!

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by check for conflicting jar files in libext folder.

Comment: Hey can you please tell Exactly how did you resolve this problem ?

Comment: most of the error that where showing in the terminal where due to conflicting libraries so I removed them from the libext folder of the oozie.

Comment: Indeed, a more detailed answer would help